# Update page content in wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress, automation

I'm currently working on a wordpress website which serves as a calendar. For this I'm using the plug-in **TablePress**. The page for the current week looks like this:

`[table id=17 /]` - Currently we got the 17th week of this year.

The id is the current number of the week, which needs to be manually changed every Monday. My question is now: Can this number get changed automatically (e.g. with php or a wordpress plug-in)?

Comment: Set up a cron (in your theme's functions.php or write a tiny plugin) to execute on monday 00:01, repeated weekly. In that cron task, update the page with current week. Profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$week = date('W');

$shortcode = sprintf(
    '[table id=%1$s]',
    $week
);
echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
```

You cannot pass a dynamic parameter directly to the shortcode, so you need to use the `do_shortcode` function. Then instead of passing the number 17, you get the current week number from the PHP function `date`.

Edit:
Create a new file inside your child theme named `page-calendar.php`. Inside add this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Calendar Page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

$week = date('W');

$shortcode = sprintf(
    '[table id=%1$s]',
    $week
);
echo do_shortcode( '[full_width padding="0 1px 0 0"]' . do_shortcode($shortcode) . '[/full_width]');
```

Then, on the page that you originally had the table shortcode, delete everything and on the dropdown on the right sidebar, change the template to the new one "Calendar Page" and save it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! :)
Do I add this to the page itself or do I need to add it somewhere else (e.g. in a php file). I haven't worked with Wordpress yet and just got this task at work.

Comment: You need to add it on a PHP file. Do you have any other content on the same page or just this shortcode?

Comment: The full content of the page is: `[full_width padding="0 1px 0 0"][table id=17 /][/full_width]`. So it's not that much i suppose.

Comment: Okay this works seamlessly! Thanks a lot - especially for the detailed explanation. The only problem I got now is: This way the table is displayed as plain text. Therefor I need to figure out how to add this into another .php skript. So I get the page layout back.